# Console input in 32-bit Protected mode

Tags: c, console, operating-system, osdev

I am currently working on my OS. I've started building it since a-day before yesterday. My OS is command-based.

This is my Kernel.c(The main file):

```
#include "include/screen.h"
#include "include/kb.h"
#include "include/string.h"
#include "data/userdata.c"

kmain()
{
       clearScreen();
       print("Halcyon OS 1.05 Beta ");


       while (1)
       {
                print("\nhalcyon@halcyon ~\n$  ");

                string ch = readStr();
                if(strEql(ch,"cmd")!=0)
                {
                        print("\nYou are already in cmd\n");
                }
                else if(strEql(ch,"clear")!=0)
                {
                        clearScreen();
                }
                else if(strEql(ch,"help")!=0)
                {
                        print("Halcyon help.");
                }
                else if(strEql(ch,"")!=0)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                else
                {
                        print("\nNo command found:");print(ch);
                        break;
                }
       }// end while loop!

}
```

And here is kb.h (I've made it for keyboard support.):

```
    #ifndef KB_H
#define KB_H
#include "screen.h"
#include "system.h"
#include "types.h"

string readStr()
{
    char buff;
    string buffstr;
    uint8 i = 0;
    uint8 reading = 1;
    while(reading)
    {
        if(inportb(0x64) & 0x1)                 
        {
            switch(inportb(0x60))
            { 
      /*case 1:
                printch('(char)27);           Escape button
                buffstr[i] = (char)27;
                i++;
                break;*/
        case 2:
                printch('1');
                buffstr[i] = '1';
                i++;
                break;
        case 3:
                printch('2');
                buffstr[i] = '2';
                i++;
                break;
        case 4:
                printch('3');
                buffstr[i] = '3';
                i++;
                break;
        case 5:
                printch('4');
                buffstr[i] = '4';
                i++;
                break;
        case 6:
                printch('5');
                buffstr[i] = '5';
                i++;
                break;
        case 7:
                printch('6');
                buffstr[i] = '6';
                i++;
                break;
        case 8:
                printch('7');
                buffstr[i] = '7';
                i++;
                break;
        case 9:
                printch('8');
                buffstr[i] = '8';
                i++;
                break;
        case 10:
                printch('9');
                buffstr[i] = '9';
                i++;
                break;
        case 11:
                printch('0');
                buffstr[i] = '0';
                i++;
                break;
        case 12:
                printch('-');
                buffstr[i] = '-';
                i++;
                break;
        case 13:
                printch('=');
                buffstr[i] = '=';
                i++;
                break;
        case 14:
                printch('\b');
                i--;
                buffstr[i] = 0;
                break;
       /* case 15:
                printch('\t');          Tab button
                buffstr[i] = '\t';
                i++;
                break;*/
        case 16:
                printch('q');
                buffstr[i] = 'q';
                i++;
                break;
        case 17:
                printch('w');
                buffstr[i] = 'w';
                i++;
                break;
        case 18:
                printch('e');
                buffstr[i] = 'e';
                i++;
                break;
        case 19:
                printch('r');
                buffstr[i] = 'r';
                i++;
                break;
        case 20:
                printch('t');
                buffstr[i] = 't';
                i++;
                break;
        case 21:
                printch('y');
                buffstr[i] = 'y';
                i++;
                break;
        case 22:
                printch('u');
                buffstr[i] = 'u';
                i++;
                break;
        case 23:
                printch('i');
                buffstr[i] = 'i';
                i++;
                break;
        case 24:
                printch('o');
                buffstr[i] = 'o';
                i++;
                break;
        case 25:
                printch('p');
                buffstr[i] = 'p';
                i++;
                break;
        case 26:
                printch('[');
                buffstr[i] = '[';
                i++;
                break;
        case 27:
                printch(']');
                buffstr[i] = ']';
                i++;
                break;
        case 28:
               // printch('\n');
               // buffstr[i] = '\n';
                  i++;
               reading = 0;
                break;
      /*  case 29:
                printch('q');           Left Control
                buffstr[i] = 'q';
                i++;
                break;*/
        case 30:
                printch('a');
                buffstr[i] = 'a';
                i++;
                break;
        case 31:
                printch('s');
                buffstr[i] = 's';
                i++;
                break;
        case 32:
                printch('d');
                buffstr[i] = 'd';
                i++;
                break;
        case 33:
                printch('f');
                buffstr[i] = 'f';
                i++;
                break;
        case 34:
                printch('g');
                buffstr[i] = 'g';
                i++;
                break;
        case 35:
                printch('h');
                buffstr[i] = 'h';
                i++;
                break;
        case 36:
                printch('j');
                buffstr[i] = 'j';
                i++;
                break;
        case 37:
                printch('k');
                buffstr[i] = 'k';
                i++;
                break;
        case 38:
                printch('l');
                buffstr[i] = 'l';
                i++;
                break;
        case 39:
                printch(';');
                buffstr[i] = ';';
                i++;
                break;
        case 40:
                printch((char)44);               //   Single quote (')
                buffstr[i] = (char)44;
                i++;
                break;
        case 41:
                printch((char)44);               // Back tick (`)
                buffstr[i] = (char)44;
                i++;
                break;
     /* case 42:                                 Left shift 
                printch('q');
                buffstr[i] = 'q';
                i++;
                break;
        case 43:                                 \ (< for somekeyboards)   
                printch((char)92);
                buffstr[i] = 'q';
                i++;
                break;*/
        case 44:
                printch('z');
                buffstr[i] = 'z';
                i++;
                break;
        case 45:
                printch('x');
                buffstr[i] = 'x';
                i++;
                break;
        case 46:
                printch('c');
                buffstr[i] = 'c';
                i++;
                break;
        case 47:
                printch('v');
                buffstr[i] = 'v';
                i++;
                break;                
        case 48:
                printch('b');
                buffstr[i] = 'b';
                i++;
                break;               
        case 49:
                printch('n');
                buffstr[i] = 'n';
                i++;
                break;                
        case 50:
                printch('m');
                buffstr[i] = 'm';
                i++;
                break;               
        case 51:
                printch(',');
                buffstr[i] = ',';
                i++;
                break;                
        case 52:
                printch('.');
                buffstr[i] = '.';
                i++;
                break;            
        case 53:
                printch('/');
                buffstr[i] = '/';
                i++;
                break;            
        case 54:
                printch('.');
                buffstr[i] = '.';
                i++;
                break;            
        case 55:
                printch('/');
                buffstr[i] = '/';
                i++;
                break;            
      /*case 56:
                printch(' ');           Right shift
                buffstr[i] = ' ';
                i++;
                break;*/           
        case 57:
                printch(' ');
                buffstr[i] = ' ';
                i++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    buffstr[i] = 0;                   
    return buffstr;
}
#endif
```

And at last the string.h(This has function to compare two strings.):

```
#ifndef STRING_H
#define STRING_H

#include "types.h"
uint16 strlength(string ch)
{
        uint16 i = 1;
        while(ch[i++]);  
        return --i;
}


uint8 strEql(string ch1,string ch2)                     
{
        uint8 result = 1;
        uint8 size = strlength(ch1);
        if(size != strlength(ch2)) result =0;
        else 
        {
        uint8 i = 0;
        for(i;i<=size;i++)
        {
                if(ch1[i] != ch2[i]) result = 0;
        }
        }
        return result;
}


#endif
```

But the problem is that even if enter the correct command like 'cmd', it only sometimes says 'No command found: cm' and sometimes it works! It goes sometimes correct and says: 'You're already in cmd!'

Also, it is recognizing it as 'cm' not 'cmd'.

And if I write in kernel.c: "print("Hello");" then it will print: 'Hell' not 'Hello'! It misses the last character.

I don't know what's wrong with my program.
I use gcc to compile it, platform is Linux Ubuntu. The sometimes work and sometimes not. But if I compile my kernel with Windows the command never works.

Please help! Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In 'strEql' if I write 'if(strEql(ch,"cmd"))' then also it's the same.

Answer (score 2):

Your string length function is wrong:

```
uint16 strlength(string ch)
{
        uint16 i = 1;
        while(ch[i++]);  
        return --i;
}
```

Assuming the string is "cmd", then you start and check if the second character, `m`, is null, then the third, then finally the fourth is null. `i` starts off with 1 and increases up to 3, and finally gets decremented to 2.

Also it would fail on zero length strings.

The consequence is, that you are not printing enough in your print function.

```
unit16 strlength(string ch) {
  unit16 l = 0;
  while (ch[l]) {
    ++l;
  }
  return l;
}
```

To find out why the comparison fails I'd need to know what type `string` actually is.

If it's a `char *`, then this is actually undefined behaviour, as your writing into some random memory.

If it's a `char [N]` then out won't work either, because that array decays to a pointer on return. And that pointer points to a local variable with automatic storage, so it is no longer valid after function return.

---

OK, it's a pointer. Pointers point to memory, where you then store the actual data. To have this working you need

1. Memory to store the data to
2. Set the pointer to point to that memory.

Normally one would allocate memory via `malloc`, but in the context of operating system development you'd first have to implement that yourself.

You cold use a buffer with automatic storage (on the stack) in the caller:

```
char buffer[20];
size_t num_read = read_into(buffer, 20);
// pass the pointer to the memory for the data plus the maximal characters this buffer can hold.

size_t read_into (char * buffer, size_t max) {
  // read up to Max characters into the
  // buffer, don't forget to count the 0 at the end.
}
```

Judging from the rest of your code, you seem to be fairly new to C programming. While writing an operating system kernel is a fun task, you'll have more fun doing it when you understand the basics first.

---

Since you're writing to random memory locations with those uninitialised `char *` you don't know where you store the data. This could be "normal", free memory. Then everything will work as expected. But you could also write to memory mapped device information or even your own code, making it impossible to predict what might happen.

Comment: Yep it's char *. What it should be?

Comment: Now you should look my edits. They all are unbelievable! Please give the answer after you read my edits.